# Can we use existing keystore and app signing key for private key whereas new keystore-file for generating an upload key for google play app signing

Tags: android, android-app-bundle, android-app-signing

I have an existing app in google play store and I would like to enroll into app signing. The existing key which I use to manually sign the published app (updates)was back from 2012 and even though I can generate a private key file (pepk), when doing the 3rd optional step of upload key, the google play console errors saying, the key file being used is too weak.

Is there a way where I can use the existing keystore-signing key to generate and upload a pepk (private) file for app signing, whereas generate another local keystore which a stronger key for using as upload key?
Is it mandatory to use the same keystore-signing key for both the private and upload key process?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally *not* use the same key for the app signing key and the upload key since they have different levels of sensitivity: if the latter is compromised you can just reset it with no long term impact, while if the former is compromised your users are effectively at risk of receiving an app update that was not built by you and there is little you can do (there is for that case a key upgrade option but that only affects *new* users of your app, not users who already have your app installed).

When you enroll in Play Signing, I would thus recommend to generate a new strong upload key, independent from your app signing key.